# Java GUI Overlay

Tags: java, user-interface, overlay

Hey, I want to make an little window like the sort of thing used by Teamspeak/Ventrillo or Steam/xFire where a window can be shown while still in a fullscreen game using Java. There was a similar question/answer ("How to create an overlay window in Java?") but that doesn't work for the particular game (EVE) whereas the previously mentioned overlays work just fine. What's the missing element? Or is it an entirely different method?

Answer (score 0):

One part of the solution might be to become part of the application itself. You can get your class loaded into any Java application by means of the [Java Accessibility API](http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/accessibility/docs/jaccess-1.3/doc/index.html).

Comment: Alas, EVE isn't written in Java

Comment: If only. A little more research and it looks like it's DirectX's handiwork in the examples, but I'm still at a loss of how to do it in Java.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, doing some more searching and a lot more fiddling, I've discovered that a great deal of what I require for my prospective program simply isn't possible in Java. I do believe I'll be jumping over to C++.

Comment: That's what I would have expected as well.  You should probably mark this as your accepted answer.